# Reading data from cvs file and converting data into multidimensional array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I'm new to Swift. I can read data (many rows and columns of names and mailing addresses) from csv file format. I have several of these files, so I created a function just to read the files and extract the data into a multidimensional array(s) - names, addresses, city, state, country. I read each of the lines from the file and try to append it to multidimensional array but I get errors - either index out of range or file type mismatch. What's the best way to enable this. See code below.

```
func getMailing(fileName: String) -> ([[String]])? {
   let totalList = 243
   var tempList: [String] = []
   var arrayList = [[String]]()
   guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "csv") else {
       print("File Error")
       arrayList = [[""]]
       return (arrayList)
   }
   do {

       // get mailing data from file
       let content = try String(contentsOf:path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

       // separate each line entry
       tempList = content.components(separatedBy: "\r\n")
       for index in 0...totalList - 1 {

          // get each line from list and post into an array
          let singleLine = tempList[index].components(separatedBy: ",").dropFirst().prefix(5)  

          // store each line data into into a multidimensional array for easy retrieval         
          arrayList[index].append(singleLine)
          }
    }
    return (arrayList)
} catch {
    print("File Error")
    arrayList = [[""]]
    return (arrayList)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've shown, it looks like you're trying to change the values of two different empty arrays 243 times. You have a loop setup to iterate based on your `totalList` property, but where you got that value, I have no idea. It would be wise to determine that value programmatically if you can.

You're setting both `tempList` and `arrayList` as empty arrays:

```
var tempList: [String] = []
var arrayList = [[String]]()
```

But then you're going through a loop and trying to change the value of an entry that doesn't even exist, hence your index out of range error. You need to first add something to both these arrays, because right now they are empty. It's probably crashing the first time through the loop when you try to set `singleLine` to `tempList[index].components(separatedBy: ",").dropFirst().prefix(5)`, because you're saying `tempList[0].components(separatedBy: ",").dropFirst().prefix(5)`, while there isn't an entry for `tempList` at index `0` because it's still empty! If you're going to loop through an array, it's always wise to do it based on the count of the array, or at least a quick fix when you need to use an index from two different arrays:

```
// Get the maximum times you can iterate based on the lowest count from each array
let maxLoop = min(tempList.count - 1, arrayList.count - 1)
for index in 0...maxLoop {

      // get each line from list and post into an array
      let singleLine = tempList[index].components(separatedBy: ",").dropFirst().prefix(5)  

      // store each line data into into a multidimensional array for easy retrieval         
      arrayList[index].append(singleLine)
 }
```

Now that little chunk of code above won't even go through the loop once, because both arrays are still empty. You need to somewhere take your mailing data and parse it so that you can populate `tempList` and `arrayList`